# How to UV map a procedural cylinder mesh? (Unity)

Tags: unity, procedural-generation, 3d-meshes, uv-mapping

I have a script that generates a procedural cylinder.
Each side is a quad that consists of two triangles.
The two triangles share vertexes, so, a side with two triangles is defined by 4 points.

The mesh generates fine as you see here:

[image]

However, I am unable to UV map it correctly.
My current progress has led me here:

[image]

With a different texture you can see how it stretches at certain points.
If the first quad is the "front" of the cylinder, then these points occur on each side.

[image]

I thought it would work to use the vertex data directly as UV points, but I can't get it to work.

Here is the (old) script.

```
private void _CreateSegmentSides()
{
    if(m_Sides > 2) {

        float angleStep = 360.0f / (float)m_Sides;
        BranchSegment seg = new BranchSegment(m_NextID++);
        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, angleStep, 0.0f);
        float height = m_SegmentStartLength;
        int max = m_Sides - 1;
        int index_tr = 0, index_tl = 3, index_br = 2, index_bl = 1;
        float angle = 0f;

        // Make first triangles.
        seg.vertexes.Add(rotation * (new Vector3(m_Radius, height, 0f)));       // top right
        seg.vertexes.Add(rotation * (new Vector3(m_Radius, 0f, 0f)));           // bottom left
        seg.vertexes.Add(rotation * seg.vertexes[seg.vertexes.Count - 1]);      // bottom right
        seg.vertexes.Add(rotation * seg.vertexes[seg.vertexes.Count - 3]);      // top left

        // Add triangle indices.
        seg.triangles.Add(index_tr);    // 0
        seg.triangles.Add(index_bl);    // 1
        seg.triangles.Add(index_br);    // 2
        seg.triangles.Add(index_tr);    // 0
        seg.triangles.Add(index_br);    // 2
        seg.triangles.Add(index_tl);    // 3

        // UV.
        seg.uv.Add(rotation * seg.vertexes[seg.vertexes.Count - 4]);
        seg.uv.Add(rotation * seg.vertexes[seg.vertexes.Count - 3]);
        seg.uv.Add(rotation * seg.vertexes[seg.vertexes.Count - 2]);
        seg.uv.Add(rotation * seg.vertexes[seg.vertexes.Count - 1]);

        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
        {
            Debug.Log("add side ("+(i+1).ToString()+"/"+ max.ToString()+ ") angle: " + angle.ToString());

            // First triangle.
            seg.vertexes.Add(rotation * seg.vertexes[seg.vertexes.Count - 2]); 

            seg.triangles.Add(seg.vertexes.Count - 1);  // new vertex
            seg.triangles.Add(seg.vertexes.Count - 2);  // shared
            seg.triangles.Add(seg.vertexes.Count - 3);  // shared

            seg.uv.Add(rotation * seg.vertexes[seg.vertexes.Count - 1]);

            // Second triangle.
            seg.vertexes.Add(rotation * seg.vertexes[seg.vertexes.Count - 2]);

            seg.triangles.Add(seg.vertexes.Count - 3);  // shared
            seg.triangles.Add(seg.vertexes.Count - 2);  // shared
            seg.triangles.Add(seg.vertexes.Count - 1);  // new vertex

            seg.uv.Add(rotation * seg.vertexes[seg.vertexes.Count - 1]);

            angle += angleStep;
        }
        m_Segments.Add(seg);
    }
}
```

I've been at this all day, what is going wrong here ??

**Edit: Current progress, updated code**

```
    // Making the first two UV coords:

rad = angle * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
ux = rad * m_Radius;

uy =  seg.vertexes[0].y;
seg.uv.Add(rotation * new Vector2(ux, uy));

uy = seg.vertexes[1].y;
seg.uv.Add(rotation * new Vector2(ux, uy));

// in the loop
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
{
    angle += angleStep;
    Debug.Log("add side (" + (i + 1).ToString() + "/" + max.ToString() + ") angle: " + angle.ToString());

    rad = angle * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
    ux = rad * m_Radius;

    // First vertex.
    seg.vertexes.Add(rotation * seg.vertexes[seg.vertexes.Count - 2]);

    seg.triangles.Add(seg.vertexes.Count - 1);  // new vertex
    seg.triangles.Add(seg.vertexes.Count - 2);  // shared
    seg.triangles.Add(seg.vertexes.Count - 3);  // shared

    // UV
    uy = seg.vertexes[seg.vertexes.Count - 1].y;
    seg.uv.Add(rotation * new Vector2(ux, uy));

    // Second vertex.
    seg.vertexes.Add(rotation * seg.vertexes[seg.vertexes.Count - 2]);

    seg.triangles.Add(seg.vertexes.Count - 3);  // shared
    seg.triangles.Add(seg.vertexes.Count - 2);  // shared
    seg.triangles.Add(seg.vertexes.Count - 1);  // new vertex

    // UV
    uy = seg.vertexes[seg.vertexes.Count - 1].y;
    seg.uv.Add(rotation * new Vector2(ux, uy));
}

And trying to fix the last to the first section
rad = 360f * Mathf.Deg2Rad;  // (I've tried keeping the angle from the loop, but that didn't solve it either)
ux = rad * m_Radius;

uy = seg.vertexes[seg.vertexes.Count - 2].y;
seg.uv.Add(rotation * new Vector2(ux, uy));

uy = seg.vertexes[seg.vertexes.Count - 1].y;
seg.uv.Add(rotation * new Vector2(ux, uy));
```

[image]

[image: this is the seam from the last section meeting the first]

**Edit: Implemented the suggestion from the second comment.**

Okay, so I'm going over the calculated UV values in a second loop after the part that I've posted, then I use the rounded value from `UVx_max / UVx_max_rounded_to_int` to multiply each UV to adjust the UV tiling.
This works! (I wonder if it is possible to do it without a second loop?)
There is a visible line (normal related?) on the seam even if the texture is seamless. I am calling `RecalculateNormals()` on the last part of the mesh creation.

[image]

**Edit: Implementation of the corrected code:**

```
private void _CreateSegmentSides2()
    {
        if(m_Sides > 2)
        { 
            float           angleStep   = 360.0f / (float)m_Sides;
            BranchSegment   seg         = new BranchSegment(m_NextID++);
            Quaternion      rotation    = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, angleStep, 0.0f);
            float           height      = m_SegmentStartLength;
            float           angle       = 0f;
            int             max         = m_Sides - 1;
            float ux, uy, rad;

            // Make first side.
            seg.vertexes.Add(rotation * (new Vector3(m_RadiusTop, height, 0f)));    // tr
            seg.vertexes.Add(rotation * (new Vector3(m_RadiusBottom, 0f, 0f)));     // bl
            seg.vertexes.Add(rotation * seg.vertexes[seg.vertexes.Count - 1]);      // br
            seg.vertexes.Add(rotation * seg.vertexes[seg.vertexes.Count - 3]);      // tl

            // Add triangle indices.
            seg.triangles.Add(0);
            seg.triangles.Add(1);
            seg.triangles.Add(2);
            seg.triangles.Add(0);
            seg.triangles.Add(2);
            seg.triangles.Add(3);

            // Making the first two normals:
            if (m_CustomNormals) { 
                seg.normals.Add(seg.vertexes[0].normalized);  // Points "out" of the cylinder.
                seg.normals.Add(seg.normals[0]);
            }

            // Making the first two UV coords:
            float circumferenceTop      = Mathf.PI * 2.0f * m_RadiusTop; // We know this in advance.
            float circumferenceBottom   = Mathf.PI * 2.0f * m_RadiusBottom;
            float uvScaleTop            = Mathf.Max(1, Mathf.Round(circumferenceTop)) / circumferenceTop;
            float uvScaleBottom         = Mathf.Max(1, Mathf.Round(circumferenceBottom)) / circumferenceBottom;
            float uvScaleDiff           = Mathf.Abs(uvScaleBottom - uvScaleTop);

            // UV starts here.
            rad = angle * Mathf.Deg2Rad;

            ux = 0;
            uy = seg.vertexes[0].y * uvScaleTop;
            seg.uv.Add(new Vector2(ux, uy));

            uy = seg.vertexes[1].y * uvScaleBottom;
            seg.uv.Add(new Vector2(ux, uy));

            // The remaining sides.
            for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
            {
                angle += angleStep;
                rad = angle * Mathf.Deg2Rad;

                // First vertex.
                seg.vertexes.Add(rotation * seg.vertexes[seg.vertexes.Count - 2]);

                seg.triangles.Add(seg.vertexes.Count - 1);  // new vertex
                seg.triangles.Add(seg.vertexes.Count - 2);  // shared
                seg.triangles.Add(seg.vertexes.Count - 3);  // shared

                // UV: x = arc length around the cylinder, y = height, scaled to tile uniformly.
                ux = (rad * m_RadiusTop) * uvScaleTop;
                uy = seg.vertexes[seg.vertexes.Count - 1].y * uvScaleTop;
                seg.uv.Add(new Vector2(ux, uy));

                // Normal: rotate normal from the previous column.
                if(m_CustomNormals) { seg.normals.Add(rotation * seg.normals[seg.normals.Count - 1]);  }

                // Second vertex.
                seg.vertexes.Add(rotation * seg.vertexes[seg.vertexes.Count - 2]);

                seg.triangles.Add(seg.vertexes.Count - 3);  // shared
                seg.triangles.Add(seg.vertexes.Count - 2);  // shared
                seg.triangles.Add(seg.vertexes.Count - 1);  // new vertex

                // UV: x is the same, update y for new vertical position.
                ux = (rad * m_RadiusBottom) * uvScaleBottom;
                uy = seg.vertexes[seg.vertexes.Count - 1].y * uvScaleBottom;
                seg.uv.Add(new Vector2(ux, uy));

                // Normal: copy previous normal.
                if(m_CustomNormals) { seg.normals.Add(seg.normals[seg.normals.Count - 1]); }
            }

            // Last UV to connect the seam.
            rad = 360f * Mathf.Deg2Rad;

            ux = (rad * m_RadiusTop) * uvScaleTop;
            uy = seg.vertexes[1].y * uvScaleTop;
            seg.uv.Add(new Vector2(ux, uy));

            ux = (rad * m_RadiusBottom) * uvScaleBottom;
            uy = seg.vertexes[0].y * uvScaleBottom;
            seg.uv.Add(new Vector2(ux, uy));

            m_Segments.Add(seg);
        }
    }
```

Custom normals:

[image]

Automatic normals by unity:

[image]

UV skew on different top and bottom radius:

[image]

(Seems like the UV is rotated ever so slightly sideways with each side, making it really messed up when it comes back around. height is also oddly scaled)

Comment: I've used with success a Cylinder from this Javascript module: https://github.com/ataber/primitive-cylinder

It has correct UV mapping, it is for WebGL in javascript, and it represents the mesh in form of simplicial complex (a point XYZ is an array of 3 numbers) and the code is quite easy to read/follow - also if you're not familiar with javascript I think.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use (rotated) vertex positions as UV coordinates. When you're using this to look up into a 2D texture, only the x & y values are used and the z is ignored, giving you a [planar projection](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2018/ENU/Maya-Modeling/files/GUID-B6519472-C0ED-4C07-99C6-12107A3509D9-htm.html):

[image: Diagram of planar projection from above link]

The effect is like shining your texture onto the object using an orthographic projector, along one directional axis. Portions of your model perpendicular to that axis catch the image flat-on, and you get a nice undistorted appearance there.

But as the surface turns diagonally to the axis, the image gets stretched. In the worst case, imagine a long edge of your model running parallel to the projection axis. Every point on that edge maps to the same pixel in the source image, so that one point of colour gets smeared out along the whole edge.

For a cylinder, you'll more often want to use a cylindrical projection:

[image: Diagram of cylindrical projection]

Here, the U (x) coordinate of our UV is our arc-length around the cylinder, and our V (y) coordinate is the vertical position of the vertex.

You can get the arc-length value by multiplying the total angle stepped so far (in radians) by the radius of your cylinder.

Note though that this has a discontinuity, where 360 degrees wraps around to 0 degrees. Here we'll want to duplicate the column of vertices we started with, so we have two sets of co-incident vertices with identical positions & normals: one to be the let edge of the texture sheet we've wrapped around our cylinder, and one to be the right edge.

You may also want to apply some scaling to your UVs so that one complete trip around the cylinder takes you an integer distance in texture space. That way you can use a tiling texture and completely erase the seam at the 360-to-0 wraparound line.

---

Here's a corrected version of your code:

```
// Making the first two normals:
seg.normals.Add(seg.vertices[0].normalized);  // Points "out" of the cylinder.
seg.normals.Add(seg.normals[0]);

// Making the first two UV coords:
float circumference = Mathf.PI * 2.0f * m_Radius; // We know this in advance.
float uvScale = Mathf.Max(1, Mathf.Round(circumference)) / circumference;
// No second loop required for fix-up - we can scale as we go.

uy =  seg.vertexes[0].y * uvScale;
seg.uv.Add(new Vector2(0, uy));

uy = seg.vertexes[1].y * uvScale;
seg.uv.Add(new Vector2(0, uy));


// in the loop
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
{
    angle += angleStep;
    Debug.Log("add side (" + (i + 1).ToString() + "/" + max.ToString() + ") angle: " + angle.ToString());

    // First vertex.
    seg.vertexes.Add(rotation * seg.vertexes[seg.vertexes.Count - 2]);

    seg.triangles.Add(seg.vertexes.Count - 1);  // new vertex
    seg.triangles.Add(seg.vertexes.Count - 2);  // shared
    seg.triangles.Add(seg.vertexes.Count - 3);  // shared

    // UV: x = arc length around the cylinder, y = height, scaled to tile uniformly.
    ux = angle * Mathf.Deg2Rad * m_Radius * uvScale;
    uy = seg.vertexes[seg.vertexes.Count - 1].y * uvScale;
    seg.uv.Add(new Vector2(ux, uy) * uvScale);

    // Normal: rotate normal from the previous column.
    seg.normals.Add(rotation * seg.normals[seg.normals.Count - 1]);

    // Second vertex.
    seg.vertexes.Add(rotation * seg.vertexes[seg.vertexes.Count - 2]);

    seg.triangles.Add(seg.vertexes.Count - 3);  // shared
    seg.triangles.Add(seg.vertexes.Count - 2);  // shared
    seg.triangles.Add(seg.vertexes.Count - 1);  // new vertex

    // UV: x is the same, update y for new vertical position.
    uy = seg.vertexes[seg.vertexes.Count - 1].y * uvScale;
    seg.uv.Add(new Vector2(ux, uy));

    // Normal: copy previous normal.
    seg.normals.Add(seg.normals[seg.normals.Count - 1]);
}
```

Now you don't have to ask Unity to calculate normals automatically: you've provided exactly the normals you want. Just watch out for floating point rounding errors, where applying `max` incremental rotations / angle additions might not bring you to exactly the total you expect. If that becomes a problem, you can do something like...

```
angle = Mathf.Lerp(0, 360.0f, i/(max - 1.0f));
```

Comment: What a great explanation, and yes, it was exactly this that was the problem! I appreciate this so, so much.
I managed to get the UV coords correct, although I am not sure how I would scale it to fit 1:1. I'm also not sure how to make it seamless. I tried adding 2(x,y 0 deg) UV points at the start, then loop around, and then add 2(x,y 360 deg) to the end, however I am still seeing an edge.

Comment: This could be because your UVs' x starts at 0, and runs to something non-integer, like say `2*pi = 6.28318...`. This would mean the left edge of your UV is on the left edge of the texture, and the right edge falls 28.318...% of the way between the left & right edges. To keep the mapping seamless, round your maximum UV x coordinate to the nearest integer, then multiply all your UVs by `roundedMaximumX / maximumX`. This will ensure your UV sheet begins & ends at the same part of the tiling texture.

Comment: Thank you, again. This was exactly the problem and I solved it by implementing it as you said. There is just one issue that I noticed, which is visible from the beginning - there is a hard shift in the shading where the seam is. Why do you think this occurs?

Comment: Most likely your normals at the doubled-up vertices disagree with one another. If you're auto-generating the normals, then because these vertices are not shared between triangles on the two sides of the seam, Unity can't tell that you want a smooth blend there. The solution is to manually provide a normal for each vertex, and ensure the normals provided to vertices on either side of a seam match one another.

Comment: Right again. I set the last side to share triangle indices with the first. Then calling unity's RecalculateNormals() makes it look smooth again. Although it did do something strange to the UV map on the last side only. But I will get back to that tomorrow. Thank you so much. You have been a tremendous help and I have learned a lot! I would upvote you 10 times more if I could.

Comment: If you share the vertices, then you can't create a UV seam  The UV seam relies on having two different sets of vertices — one for the left edge of the texture sheet, and one for the right edge. If you share them, then the column one-before the right edge will be connected allll the way back to the left edge in UV space, crunching the whole texture wrap into the space of one column of faces: not what you want.

Comment: I was thinking if I am creating a lot of the objects that incorporate this cylinder, it would be better for performance to have as less work as possible, thus sharing vertices. But do you think this is unnecessary? Should each side be 6 vertices instead?

Comment: Sharing one column of vertices is not a significant savings, especially when it fails to give you the visual effect you want. Games with much more complex models than the one you're showing use UV seams (unshared vertices) all the time.

Comment: I rewrote it so that each face has its own 4 vertices, and I used the UV procedure you described. Now both the UV, normals and vertices are all perfect. Thank you again :)

Comment: I just noticed your code. I will have a go at it and see how it pans out. In my own version I also added a lower and upper radius so that the cylinder's top and bottom can be scaled differently, and I was also relying on Unity's automatic normal calculating function.

Comment: There are two issues with the current version; 1 - the normals doesn't seem to be having an effect. It's much brighter than the auto normals. 2 - I've applied variables for top & bottom radius, circumference and scale and applied them where applicable, but when the radiuses are different, the smaller triangle scales really tiny and the bigger one scales somewhat decent size-wise, but skewed.

Comment: It sounds like you might want to post a new question about your new challenges. We won't be able to troubleshoot those issues in detail in the comments.

Comment: I updated the post with new code and pictures, but if you think it's a larger issue than something you can spot and see is wrong right away, I'll make a new post. :)

Comment: Please do not make me repeat myself. This is a different problem than the one you started with, and should be asked as a new question. (After searching for [existing Q&A covering the relevant topics](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/148082/39518), of course. If you can solve this with existing answers, even better)

Comment: I understand. Thank you for the help and the link. I will see if I am able to implement it by my self first. :)